# How to get gcc to skip errors, but still output them.

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, compiler-errors

is it possible to force gcc to report errors, but keep compiling past them? Essentially I'm trying to generate a list of errors in a .c file, but gcc always terminates at the first error. I've been googling for a while and this isn't an obvious one to solve from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up-to-date versions of GCC will attempt to skip certain errors where possible.

Say the body of `foo(){...` contains a const-violation. The translation unit will not produce an object file but any decent compiler will continue past this error into `bar(){...`

Other errors are unrecoverable. If you miss out some curly braces there's no reasonable guess that can be mades as to how to proceed.

Comment: Does the compiler indicate whether an error is unrecoverable? For example below I'll post some output. make continues on to the next object, but it's unclear if the previous gcc error resulted in a termination of that object's compilation, or if it actually continued but happened to not encounter any more errors.

Comment: CC [M]  /home/stebar01/elba/crystalhd/07032010/driver/linux/crystalhd_lnx.o
/home/stebar01/elba/crystalhd/07032010/driver/linux/crystalhd_lnx.c:356:2: error: unknown field 'ioctl' specified in initializer
/home/stebar01/elba/crystalhd/07032010/driver/linux/crystalhd_lnx.c:356:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
make[2]: [/home/stebar01/elba/crystalhd/07032010/driver/linux/crystalhd_lnx.o] Error 1 (ignored)
  CC [M]  /home/stebar01/elba/crystalhd/07032010/driver/linux/crystalhd_hw.o

Comment: I changed the ioctl stuff to unlocked_ioctl and this object compiled without a fuss, so I think the above shows an example of gcc continuing past the error! Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

GCC terminates when it can't go further.

If a compiler encounters an error, it has to guess what the correct code should be and try to follow. Effectively that means that you always need to fix the first error and re-run the compilations, since the rest will be nonsense.

Make sure that you haven't turned `-Wfatal-errors` on.

Comment: The poster seems willing to give up having any compiled output in favor of having a complete list of errors.  Some errors would not disrupt program parsing even though they would preclude output.  But others - say mismatched () or {} or "" would probably require a huge degree of intelligence to recover from to the point where subsequent parsing could be meaningful.

Comment: This is correct, I could care less at this point about an output object, I'm just concerned with an error list. Most of the errors are because I'm attempting to build a kernel module for ARCH=arm rather than x86, and there are a lot of x86 specifics in there i.e. rdtscll (reads the time stamp counter, which is x86 specific) so generally the code structure and syntax is fine.

Answer (score 0):

From [gcc online doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> -fmax-errors=n
>
> Limits the maximum number of error messages to n, at which point GCC bails out rather than attempting to continue processing the source code. If n is 0 (the default), there is no limit on the number of error messages produced. If -Wfatal-errors is also specified, then -Wfatal-errors takes precedence over this option.