# How to make GCC in cmd.exe shows all errors

Tags: c, gcc, cmd

I've been using gcc in windows cmd to compile my c codes.

Here's my cmd command which work normally:

```
gcc test.c -o myprogram
```

When there are more than one errors, like this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <foo.h>
int main()
{
    printf("bar")
}
```

It displays just this one error

```
error.c:2:19: fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory
```

compilation terminated.

instead of 3 errors:

1. no "foo.h" header file
2. printf("bar") has no semicolon
3. no return value for int main

How can I improve my cmd command to make gcc show all of its errors?

Comment: GCC cant continue past a fatal error. You need to fix it before moving on. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860568/how-to-get-gcc-to-skip-errors-but-still-output-them) might help.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me.

Answer (score 3):

The better command to invoke `gcc` in your case would be

```
  gcc -Wall -Wextra -g test.c -o myprogram
```

<sup>it is asking for [nearly] all warnings, some extra warnings, and debugging information (to use `gdb`)</sup>

However, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (or any reasonable compiler) cannot do much about a missing included file (since that missing file would probably define a lot of names needed to compile the rest of your code).

Read much more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), i.e. [cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) ...

<sup>Imagine that `foo.h` contained `#define printf(...)` (that would be a bad idea, since coding 
 `#define printf(...) do{}while(0)` would be perhaps [better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154138/841108) -but not that much, since [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) is returning an integer- and would have caught your error#2), then your code would be correct.</sup>

BTW, you probably should improve your habits and compile very often (e.g. every few minutes) your source code. Also, use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) and commit your source code several times a day (when it does compile).

If you use a good editor (e.g. [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) you can easily configure it to build your project (e.g. run [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)) thru *M-x compile* with one keypress. For a small project (less than 100 thousands lines of C source code) suitably organized in *several* [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) and using a good builder like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) recompiling it *incrementally* should take a few seconds at most, and you can afford doing that often.

Regarding missing `return` in `main` (specifically for `main`) (your error#3), this is (strangely) conforming to the [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standard §5.1.2.2.3 (of [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

> reaching the `}` that terminates the
>   `main` function returns a value of 0